# MySQL find missing numbers in (unique) NON-SEQUENTIAL integer field

Tags: mysql

I have a column of non-sequential unique integer numbers between 30 and 999.

I need to present a dropdown list populated with the available numbers.

I could use some of the solutions on this forum but they are all meant for sequential number fields.

I could also probably process this using code in my app, but that is much slower.
I believe in letting the database engine do as much of the work as possible.

Is there a way to sort a table field (i.e. create a sequential list) before processing it?

Comment: Too bad you are not using MariaDB, where you could use the pseudo table `seq_30_to_999`.  (Yes, that is exactly the name of the table -- exactly what you need for the `LEFT JOIN .. WHERE .. IS NULL`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good way to do this is to simply maintain a sequence of values from 30 to 999 in your MySQL database.  Then, you can left join as follows to generate the list of available numbers:

```sql
SELECT t1.id
FROM
(
    SELECT 30 AS id UNION ALL      -- replace this inline table
    SELECT 31 UNION ALL            -- with a formal sequence table
    ...
    SELECT 998 UNION ALL
    SELECT 999
) t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE
    t2.id IS NULL;
```

You may replace the inlined subquery aliased as `t1` above with a formal sequence table in your database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
The part in brackets is causing a bit of over thinking...

Is "t1" sort of a temp table built from values in my created table with all values?

i.e. I can replace the part in brackets with a select from my created table like:
(Where all_numbers is created table with 30-999 already in a field "number")

`SELECT t1.number FROM
(SELECT number FROM all_numbers) t1
LEFT JOIN your_table t2
    ON t2.number = t1.number
WHERE
    t2.number IS NULL;`

Comment: @JacoleGrange Actually, you just need `FROM all_numbers t1 LEFT JOIN yourTable t2` ... assuming that you already have a table `all_numbers` handy.  I only included the subquery to show you what the table contains.

Comment: Aha.

Thanks a lot.

I will try it and mark your answer...